# Pandas - efficient element comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a large multiIndex DataFrame `results_matrix` with several columns. I need to access each element of the columns `Results1` and `Results2` and select one of those elements based on an indicator variable that is stored in the column `Indicator` of the DataFrame.

Currently, I am accessing each of the elements in a for loop - however, this increases the calculation time of the program quite a lot.
Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

selected_results = pd.Series(np.nan)
# Used to iterate through the rows of the DataFrame
i = 0
for items in results_matrix['Indicator']:
    if results_matrix.iloc[i]['Indicator'] == 1:
        selected_results[i] = results_matrix.iloc[i]['Results1']
    else:
        selected_results[i] = results_matrix.iloc[i]['Results2']
    i += 1

results_matrix['SelectedResults'] = selected_results.values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
results_matrix['SelectedResults'] = np.where(results_matrix['Indicator'] == 1, 
                                             results_matrix['Results1'], 
                                             results_matrix['Results2'])
```

Sample:

```
results_matrix = pd.DataFrame({'Indicator':[1,2,3],
                               'Results1':[4,5,6],
                               'Results2':[7,8,9]})

print (results_matrix)
   Indicator  Results1  Results2
0          1         4         7
1          2         5         8
2          3         6         9

results_matrix['SelectedResults'] = np.where(results_matrix['Indicator'] == 1, 
                                             results_matrix['Results1'], 
                                             results_matrix['Results2'])

print (results_matrix)                                             
   Indicator  Results1  Results2  SelectedResults
0          1         4         7                4
1          2         5         8                8
2          3         6         9                9
```

Comment: @jezreal, Thanks so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. Now, I can get rid of a few other for / if / elif / else combinations as well.